# asyncio.sleep from within a UDP server not working

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm playing with [`asyncio` UDP server example](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server-protocol) and would like to have a `sleep` from within the `datagram_received` method.

```python
import asyncio

class EchoServerProtocol:
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Received %r from %s' % (message, addr))
        # Sleep
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('Send %r to %s' % (message, addr))
        self.transport.sendto(data, addr)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print("Starting UDP server")
# One protocol instance will be created to serve all client requests
listen = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(EchoServerProtocol,
                                       local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(listen)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

transport.close()
loop.close()
```

This fails with a `SyntaxError` on the sleep line (Python 3.5.1). Using `time.sleep` is obviously not working as it prevents any other datagram to be received. Any hints on how to solve this?

The goal is to replace this `sleep` with a real non-blocking I/O call.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `await` has to live in an `async def` (coroutine). To do so, you must fire a call via `asyncio.ensure_future`.

```py
def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
    asyncio.ensure_future(self.reply(data, addr))

async def reply(self, data, addr):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    self.transport.sendto(data, addr)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `ensure_future` only schedules the execution. You do not have guarantee when/how (with error) it will complete if ever.